# programatically change UIButton text and open a url

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` as an action. I would like to set a dynamic url and also a dynamic text (on view load, not on click) to it eventually.

```
@IBAction func openUrl(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitle("Hello World", forState: .Normal)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!)
}
```

The above code is working, but the button title changes to "Hello World" only after clicking it.

[image]

Comment: Do you have NSAppTransportSecurity set?  If not you will need change the http to https.

Comment: I have set it in `Info.plist`. No problem with opening the url if i'm not trying to set the title.

Comment: @Sayanee check if the IBAction is still connected to the button properly. That error gets thrown when the outlets aren't connected as well.

Comment: @kRiZ Thanks! I just checked https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvbf9as1ewhsecc/Screenshot%202016-02-12%2011.20.43.png?dl=0

No more error, but the button title is not "Hello World". It only changes upon clicking the button. Let me edit my question.

Comment: When exactly do you want the title to change?

Comment: @kRiZ on view load and it can remain so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `viewDidLoad` and set the title there. Also, create an outlet to the button if you haven't already:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    yourButtonOutlet.setTitle("Hello World", forState: .Normal)
}
```

Remove the `setTitle()` line from the IBAction.

This will set the title of your button when the view loads for your controller.

Comment: thank you @kRiZ :) I did not know that I had to create an action and then an outlet for the same button. #learningios

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement [`application(_:openURL:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:options:) in your AppDelegate. That is the method that responds to the opening of that URL. You might also want to wrap your opening call with [`canOpenURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:) to prevent this error from happening.

Answer (score 1):

//For change title of button at time of view loading :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourButtonOutlet.setTitle("Hello World", forState: .Normal)
}
```

//For open Link:

```
@IBAction func openLink(sender:UIButton){        
    var url  = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) == true  {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
    }  
}
```